# Searching for a word in sentence ending in a question

Tags: editing, word-choice

I would like to search for words in a sentence that ends with a question mark - ?

For example I have a pdf document or a word document with the following sentence:

> Which of the following describes a benefit of a data lakehouse that is
> unavailable in a traditional data warehouse?

I would like to search in the document for the word 'lakehouse' that is followed by a question mark.

A successful search would find the above sentence or the following sentence:

> Assuming the data engineer is the Delta table owner, which part of the
> Databricks Lakehouse Platform can the data engineer use to grant the
> data analysts the appropriate access?

I thought I could do a search like **lakehouse*?** but that doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about using software. Questions about how to search PDF documents would better fit elsewhere.

Comment: @user52445 Questions about using software for the purpose of writing aee on-topic here.  The question is valid.

Comment: @Chenmunka So questions about regex are on topic just because a writer uses the regex? Makes no sense to me...

Comment: @user52445 was accidently helpful. To the OP, look up regular expressions. Your PDF viewer may or may not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way I know how to do this is simply to search for `lakehouse`, and check if it's in a question or not yourself.

If the questions are formatted in a specific way (such as, the document is a Q&A, and all questions are in bold), there's usually an option to specify format in programs like Word or LibreOffice Writer; not sure about .pdf readers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no foolproof way to do this because it's not possible to reliably identify the end of a sentence in English unless you actually read and understand what's being said. The following is either one sentence or two:

- We saw John Jr. Google the question.

If you ignore this issue (and several others), you can do a search in any editor with a regex search (e.g. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#pcre) or Notepad++) using the following regex:

```
/lakehouse[^.!]*\?/gi
```

(I'm not sure if all tools support modes, like `gi`. If it doesn't you may have to lowercase the text to search in to find all the matches.)

Here's what it looks like on Regex101:

[image: the text of the question as the "test string"]

Comment: Don't you mean `/(\w)\?/` or `/(.*) ([^ ]+)\?/`? OP is looking for all the last words of all questions, not just "lakehouse".

Comment: @user52445 That's not how I understood the question: "I would like to search in the document for the word 'lakehouse' that is followed by a question mark." (This is amidst two examples that should match where "lakehouse" is not the last word.) The other answer interpreted it the same way as me.

Comment: If you continue reading, the question goes on to say: `A successful search would find the above sentence or the following sentence: "[...] access?"`

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for reaching out. Sorry for the confusion. As @user52445 pointed out, a successful search would ```find the above sentence or the following sentence: "[...] access?"```

Comment: Also, "google" is a verb and should be lowercase. I had a hard time making sense of the example sentence, because I took Google to be the last name of John Jr.

Comment: @Patterson I don't understand the question then. What are you searching for exactly, all questions?

Comment: @user52445 Most dictionaries list both capitalizations, such as [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google). The word "Jr." comes at the end of a name, not before. It is, of course, a contrived example but the situation does arise.

Comment: @Laurel Patterson is searching for the last word in each question. –– "The word Jr. comes at the end of a name." I took it for a middle initial. I guess I just saw the shape of what looked like a name to me (capitalized word-letter-word) and didn't think about the "r" in "Jr" much beyond that.